# Why do Django forms displaying as table?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Why do Django forms display as table?  I did define any table as display.

```
from django import forms

class FieldForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField(label='Field:', max_length=32)

<form action="" method="get">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

 output:

<tr><th><label for="id_field">Field:</label></th><td><input id="id_field" maxlength="32" name="field" type="text" required /></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering a form via

```
{{ form }}
```

the form's `as_table` method is called by default ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates), [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L136)). Use

```
{{ form.as_p }}
# or
{{ form.as_ul }}
```

if you want to render it as paragraphs or an unordered list. If you don't like either of those, you can still [manually render fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).